# Dynamically update tooltip date format highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to update the tooltip date format dynamically. Like on button click event the tooltip date format will be change to another one. Check out my html:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
<button id="dateFormate">changeDateFormat</button>
on Click the button date format chang to %m-%d-%y
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    tooltip: {
        xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
        shared: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4].reverse()
    }]

});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/hL8ae0yr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also define tooltip format in the series, then update a series array with new format.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hL8ae0yr/1/

```
chart.series[0].update({
            tooltip:{
                xDateFormat: '%Y/%m/%d',
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by rebuilding the chart. After the chart has been rendered I cannot find a way to access the chart.tooltip.options to reset. So you can do something like this:

```
$("#dateFormate").click(function () {
    var theChart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var initOptions = theChart.options;
    var options0 = {
        tooltip: {
            xDateFormat: '%m-%d-%y'
        }
    };

    optionsNew = Highcharts.merge(initOptions, options0);

    $('#container').highcharts(optionsNew);
});
```

This merges the new `tooltip.xDateFormat` with the existing chart options and then recreates the chart.